# How to instantiate a class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

I'm a beignner in C#, 
I want to create a new object in my main class,
How do i go about it ?

House.cs

```
namespace Assignment
{
public class House
    {
        //the class containing properties of  the house

        //Properties with their GETTERS AND SETTERS

        public int housenumber
            {
                get { return this.housenumber; }
                set { this.housenumber = value; } // Setter declaration
            }

        public string color
            {
                get { return this.color; }
                set { this.color = value; } 
            }
        public string nationality
            {
                get { return this.nationality; }
                set { this.nationality = value; } 
            }
        public string drink
            {
                get { return this.drink; }
                set { this.drink = value; } 
            }
        public string cigarrette
            {
                get { return this.cigarrette; }
                set { this.cigarrette = value; } 
            }
        public string pet
            {
                get { return this.pet; }

                set { this.pet = value; } 
            }
        public House( )
        {
        }
          }

}
```

but when compiling My main Class below, I'm receiving an error CS0246
 " The type or namespace name 'House' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Solver.cs

```
using System;
namespace Assignment
{
public class solver{
    // the main class
   static void Main()
    {
      House myhouse = new House();
    }
}
}
```

............................................................... ..................................................................

Comment: Your property setters are recursive and will fail with a stack overflow exception.

Comment: You mean the House object, like you're already doing? Yes, that's correct. You could also let the compiler infer the type automatically using `var myhouse = new House();`

Comment: Are you sure you're using C# 2.0? The 2.0 language version dates back up to 2005, and we're currently heading into C# 8.0.

Comment: Adding on John you´re better off using `public int housenumber { get; set; }`, or even better PascalCase, which is `HouseNumber`.

Comment: In your initial post you mentioned you are using `csc.exe` - are you compiling both files `House.cs` and `Solver.cs` at the same time, by providing both files as arguments to `csc.exe` eg. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070542/how-to-include-multiple-source-files-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

To begin you have your class "House" in the file "**House.cs**" with a lot of properties.

1) Be careful about naming rules violation for the property name. These words ***should*** begin with an upper case. ( drink => Drink ).

2) You can clean your code using expression body for your properties.

3) An empty constructor can be removed. 
So your class is now :

```cs
public class House
{
    /* Useless constructor. You can remove this.
        public House() { }
    */
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; } // Expression body with no violations in the name
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Drink { get; set; }
    public string Cigarrette { get; set; }
    public string Pet { get; set; }
}
```

To instantiate your object and use it and set values you can do this:

```cs
using Assignment; // Use this to import your class
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            // You can instantiate like this 
            var house = new House();
            house.Nationality = "French"; // Unique value assignation using house

            // If you want to set a lot of values for your house object do this:
            var myHouse = new House {
                Cigarrette  = "Camel" ,
                Color       = "Yellow",
                Nationality = "French"
            };

            // Now you have access to the House's properties ( if you use the using ).
            Console.WriteLine( house.Nationality   ); // French
            Console.WriteLine( myHouse.Nationality ); // French

        }
    }
}
```

And yes you have to import your "**House.cs**" with the `using Assignment`
If using doesn't work because your class House.cs is in an another project, you can do this:
Right click in the main project -> Add reference -> Add the project where House.cs is

Comment: "These words must begin with an upper case." No, it's not a "must". It's a good idea, sure - but it's definitely not causing the problem the OP has reported, nor is the empty constructor. This answer is a set of suggestions for improving the code, but it doesn't solve the problem reported by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Property is a functional class member and can't store any data itself. So you have to declare field to store data for property:

```
private string color;
public string Color
{
    get { return color; }
    set { color = value; } 
}
```

But in simple case we can declare property without explicit declaring field:

```
int Color { get; set; }
```

.NET compiler will create "hidden" and unvisible field to store data for this property.